# Can a gpu or graphic card accept both nvidia and amd driver?

Tags: 3d

I wish to know if I uninstall my present amd HD 3400 series driver and install a nvidia driver,  my PC will be working effectively without causing me to replace my graphic card hardware. 
I am also puzzled with whether if I update a gpu (graphic card) driver my opengl version will change spontaneously.

I will be grateful if I am not abandoned in this confusion

Answer (score 1):

The NVidia driver will either refuse to install as you have no NVidia card, or lie dormant until such time as you install one.

Your OpenGL version is both hardware & software dependant, but an HD 3400 will essentially be limited to v3.3 or the fallback 2.1 native

It's a legacy card & there are no further updates for it beyond 2013.

ref - http://feedback.wildfiregames.com/report/opengl/device/Mobility%20Radeon%20HD%203400

Last drivers [assuming your laptop manufacturer hasn't locked you to their own updates only]
Windows 7 32-bit - http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=legacy2&os=Windows%207%20-%2032
Windows 8 32-bit - http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop/legacy?product=legacy2&os=Windows%208%20-%2032

Comment: Thank you very much for your vital reply.
I really understand now the first question I asked.
But presently, I wish you advise me,  if you are in need of an updated opengl for a maximum graphic performance with a lock or lagacy gpu what will you do?

Comment: The OpenGL version is a feature of the hardware; no amount of software updating, even if possible, would change that. Your only solution would be to buy a new graphics card - which is of course not possible on a laptop, unless you go for some kind of external GPU solution, which I think would be a complete waste of money on an old system & provide no discernible improvement. If you are trying to run modern games on it, the rest of the machine will also be too slow to keep up.